# node.js/express/mongodb instead of apache/mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache, mongodb, express

because I need real time features like chat, notifications, instant updates of things, etc.. might be a good idea to replace ENTIRELY my website (that current uses as web server apache + mysql) with node.js (with websocket), express and mongodb ? Note that I have also the need of upload/download small and big files.

What the pro/cons of this choice ?
Or do you recommend another web server instead of node.js ?

Happy epiphany and thank you in advance.

Comment: Kind of a vague question, what does your site serve up? How much traffic?  HTML heavy or image/video heavy or both?  What you use depends on what you need done, not the opinions of people on the internet that don't know what you know about your site.  Also note, mongoDB is NoSQL, which means no joins on tables in queries; this complicates things if you need to join db data.

Comment: previsions of a huge traffic of upload and downloaded files (even too big), online viewing of text/image/audio/video/etc.. including features like chat, notifications and other.  
I don't know now if I need nosql or sql like database but mongodb was just an example, no problem for using mysql or other in node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote Chris:

> What you use depends on what you need done, not the opinions of people on the internet that don't know what you know about your site.

He is absolutely correct.  There are too many things that influence your decision.  However, let me help clarify some things which will help answer your question indirectly.

> node.js/express/mongodb instead of apache/mysql?

You don't have to use Node.js with Express or MongoDB.  They are three distinct technologies and just because you use Node.js doesn't mean you have to use MongoDB or Express.  The same thing goes with Apache and MySQL.  They have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

For your web server, use what makes sense for what you are serving up.  If you are sending primarily static files, use a traditional web server.  I will say that Nginx tends to handle heavier loads better than Apache though, so take a look at that.  For the **application** side of things though, Node.js often makes sense.  For serving up content from your application, Express is commonly used to handle boilerplate stuff.

You mention that you need to do a lot of realtime communication with clients... have you considered Socket.IO?  This gives you a web-socket-like RPC that is highly compatible due to the many transports it supports (WebSocket, long-poll JSON, etc.).  Socket.IO commonly runs on top of Node.js and can share a web server instance with Express.

You should note that you can still use a traditional web server like Nginx and Node.js at the same time.  I do this often, with Nginx proxying requests back to my Node.js servers.  This allows me to worry about logging, throttling, and blocking all in one place while keeping a nice separation of concerns.

Finally, for your data... does your data make sense in a relational model?  If so, keep a relational database such as MySQL, Postgres, or one of the many others.  Is your data structured a bit differently?  Consider one of the many NO-SQL databases that may fit your data model.  Just because you need fast data doesn't mean a particular type of database will be faster than the other.  It depends entirely on what you are doing.

I hope this clears up some of your confusion.  I encourage you to split your problem apart and think about each part of it individually before coming to a conclusion on what technologies you think go well together.